# matrices array in latex

Tags: tables

**[image: strong text]**

Hello everybody, I need a help to create this array.

Comment: Hi, welcome. I think http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67487/how-to-do-a-table-with-top-corner-removed or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64825/remove-border-of-top-left-table-cell might be helpful.

Comment: Please do not ask the [same question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356908/69818) twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
 \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
 \cline{4-6}
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
 \cline{4-6}
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & 5 & 0 & 1 \\
 \cline{4-6}
 \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
 \hline
 3 & 1 & 2 & 3\cdot2+1\cdot5+2\cdot2 & 3\cdot1+1\cdot0+2\cdot3 & 3\cdot4+1\cdot1+2\cdot2\\
 \hline
 1 & 4 & 3 &                         &                         &                        \\
 \hline
 2 & 3 & 5 &                         &                         &                        \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{AB} \\
 \end{array}
$
\end{document}
```